# Access a local repository

Tags: apt, package-management, repository

I'm trying to access a local repository which happens to be a mirror of the Ubuntu 14.04 trusty release.  The stuff all downloads and looks good, but I can't get apt-get to install any packages from it.  My `/etc/apt/sources.list` file contains:

```
deb [arch=amd64] file:///unixdepot/ubuntu/repos/14.04/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb [arch=amd64] file:///unixdepot/ubuntu/repos/14.04/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted
deb [arch=amd64] file:///unixdepot/ubuntu/repos/14.04/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted
```

The files exist in there.  When I try to use apt-get, I get:

```
root@tm1cldctll02-adm:/etc/apt# apt-get install libsm-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libsm-dev
root@tm1cldctll02-adm:/etc/apt#
```

But the file exists:

```
root@tm1cldctll02-adm:/etc/apt# find /unix*/ub*/repo*/ -name "libsm-dev*"
/unixdepot/ubuntu/repos/14.04/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libs/libsm/libsm-dev_1.2.1-2_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Did you do an `apt-get update`?

Comment: That did it!  Thanks.  Just plain spaced that out.

Answer (score 1):

When you change `apt`'s sources, you have to use `apt-get update` to make it aware of those changes. Not doing so can have weird effects, the most straightforward effect being that `apt` cannot find anything which should be present in the new source.